# How to remove all sublime snippets for a particular tab trigger?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I used to have 4 entries for the `do` sublime snippet tab trigger. I followed the technique described in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995926/how-do-i-disable-snippets-in-sublime-text-3), by renaming the appropriated files in the ruby  package directory:

```
Ruby ❯ pwd
/Users/max/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Ruby
Ruby ❯ readlink *old*
/Users/max/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Ruby/do-obj-..-end-(doo).sublime-snippet.old.sublime-snippet
/Users/max/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Ruby/downto(0)-{-n-..-}-(dow).sublime-snippet.old.sublime-snippet
Ruby ❯
```

I was able to remove 2/4 the entries; however, two still remain (see screen shot), where are these files located so I can rename them also? Or what do I need to do to remove the other two entries?

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to rename the files shown so that they *do not* end in `.sublime-snippet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the file from `do-obj-..-end-(doo).sublime-snippet` to `do-obj-..-end-(doo).old`