# Disable PHP autocomplete suggestions in Sublime Text 3

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3

I program php in Laravel and don't use the myriad of native php functions hardly ever.  So I don't need the huge list of php functions that are irrelevant to me to pop up all the time as auto-complete suggestions. 
 I want my own snippets (which are really useful and cool) to appear but nothing else.

Tried in user/preferences `"auto_complete": false`

All that does is stop the box from showing on the screen, but the suggestions are still present and will be triggered.  I want to switch them off completely, except my own snippets.

The potential of custom snippets to generate oft. used code is wonderful. Would like to add more.

But need to remove the above unnnecessaries first so it's not constantly triggering nonsense that just has to be deleted, interrupting flow.  How?

Answer (score 0):

You can add delay timer for auto complete with:

> "auto_complete_delay": *number in miliseconds*

So it will delay for auto complete trigger. This way you will hardly see it if you give it something like 2-3 minutes.

Comment: Problem is I like to hit tab and if there's any spelling mistake, I always end up with some monstrosity. e.g., typing at random, 'fdj <tab>', and I get this: fdf_set_javascript_action(fdf_document, fieldname, trigger, script) !!!

Comment: oh this will prevent tab complete as it is also a part of autocomplete, I think we need to check documentation further. Meantime you can try to look into that post which might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995926/how-do-i-disable-snippets-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: Think I solved it by setting both "tab_completion": false and "auto_complete": false.  Snippets are still triggered (but not listed in any popup), and other completions aren't (as per comments in sublime-settings default - sorry i should have read and experimented with that fully first).  Ideal would be to see snippets in a pop up, but this works for now. Thanks @Atilla